# Where to find the Jupyter connector?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Has anyone come across the `Jupyter connector` demonstrated by SW in WTC 2018 Keynote presentation. It is mentioned in the following post.

https://medium.com/wolfram-events/wolfram-technology-conference-2018-whats-new-with-wolfram-2b84b083175f

If someone knows how to setup this `Jupyter connector` or where to find it, please share. I can't find it in the documentation for version 12.

Comment: I think this is it: https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As user6014 said in a comment, the Wolfram Language kernel for Jupyter notebooks is available at the following address:

> https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

Comment: There are no releases, i.e. paclet file to install using `PacletInstall["WolframLanguageForJupyter-x.y.z.paclet"]`. (https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter/releases). I think I would need to build the paclet file using `configure-jupyter.wls build`. Should I just type this in the `cmd`. What is the syntax to use wolfram script to build the paclet file on windows 10?

Comment: Found it, `wolframscript -file configure-jupyter.wls build` works.

Comment: But one more problem. Does anyone knows how to find the path to the `JupyterBinary` for `ConfigureJupyter["Add","JupyterBinary"->"..."]` where jupyter that comes installed with anaconda distribution?